# merging two rows in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, merge, toad

The reason for me in merging two rows is because the table I'm referring to stores transactions in both Debit and Credit. therefore, whenever a transaction occurs, there will always be two new records inserted into the table, one for Debit and one for Credit. What I need to do is merge those two related transactions, for example:

[image: merging two related rows]

into something that looks like this:

[image: sample of merged row]

forgot one thing. how the Debit and Credit amount is determined is by this code:

```
CASE WHEN DTD.PART_TRAN_TYPE = 'D'
        THEN (DTD.TRAN_AMT)
        ELSE null
    END DR_Amount,
    CASE WHEN DTD.PART_TRAN_TYPE = 'C'
        THEN (DTD.TRAN_AMT)
        ELSE null
    END CR_Amount,
```

the amounts just come from one table.

Answer (score 2):

What you want here is an SQL JOIN query.

Assuming the table name is 'trans', Something like:

```
SELECT table1.TRANSACTION_ID, table1.ACCT_CURRENCY, 
    table1.DR_AMOUNT, table2.CR_AMOUNT
FROM trans table1
INNER JOIN trans table2 on table1.TRANSACTION_ID = table2.TRANSACTION_ID
```

This uses an **INNER JOIN** to join the table 'trans' with itself. We do this by giving the table an **alias** ('FROM trans table1' lets us refer to an instance of trans with 'table1'). 
The 'on' statement tells Oracle to take every record from table1 and join it to a record from table2 that has the same 'TRANSACTION_ID' field value.

Answer (score -1):

In your case  you will have a record with either Credit value or Debit value.

Consider a Table Name as TRANS_INFO with sample record

[image]

**Query :**

```
SELECT * FROM TRANS_INFO CR_TABLE 
INNER JOIN TRANS_INFO DR_TABLE ON CR_TABLE.TRANS_ID = DR_TABLE.TRANS_ID
AND (CR_TABLE.CR_AMOUNT <> '') AND (DR_TABLE.DR_AMOUNT <> '')
```

**OutPut:** As a Merged row based on `TRANS_ID`

[image]

Comment: not exactly the answer I'm looking for. I added something in my original post, please check again